# How to pass paremeters into Velocity

Tags: java, plugins, jira, velocity

I have method in my Java class.

```
public String getCorrectFormatDate(Issue issue){
    Long timespent = issue.getTimeSpent();

    if(timespent>0){
        int hours = (int) (timespent / 3600);
        int remainder = (int) (timespent - hours * 3600);
        int min = remainder / 60;
        String result = hours + "h " + min +"min";
        return result;
    }
    else{
        return "0";
    }

}
```

Also, In my velocity template I have this code

```
#foreach ($issue in $issues)
        <tr role="row">
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><a href="$action.getBaseURL()/browse/${issue.getKey()}">$issue.getKey()</a></td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">$issue.getSummary()</td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">$action.getCorrectFormatDate($issue)</td>
        #end
```

Why this my certain method isnt working?

```
$action.getCorrectFormatDate($issue)
```

threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: perhaps `$action` is null or `$issue` is null. With what you have provided I can not tell.!!!  Try replacing the problem line with $action $issue and see what is generated

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: What does it mean? 

In my velocity I use 

$webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext
 
And I have a properly configuration in xml, I can invoke method without parameters, but in this case I want to in Velocity pass parameter and theres a problem